# Filter collection by string field

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class

```
public class Code
{
    public string Code {get;set;}
}
```

For example collection contains the following:

```
01110
01111
01112
10110
20010
20011
```

The codes have mask: the first 4 symbols is like ID, the 5-th is a extension.If the collection contains more than one element with the same ID, then remove the element ending in zero.
For example above result is:

```
01111
01112
10110
20011

private List<Code> FilterCode(IEnumerable<Code> codes)
{
}
```

Comment: why does it have to be LINQ? first write an old-fashion for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get what you really want, I will try something like this: 
warning: dirty and not tested but I think this will help you.

```
public class Code
{
    public string Id { get;set; }
    public string Extension { get;set; }
    public string CodeStr { get; set; }

    public Code(string code)
    {
        CodeStr = code;
        Id = code.Remove(code.Length - 1);
        Extension = code.Substring(code.Length - 1);
    }
}

private List<Code> CodeList(IEnumerable<string> codes)
{
    var result = new List<Code>();
    foreach(string str in codes)
    {
        var code = new Code(str);

        if (result.Exists(x => x.Id == code.Id))
        {
            var items = result.Where(x => x.Id == code.Id && x.Extension == "0").ToList() ;
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                result.Remove(item);
            }

            if (code.Extension != "0")
                result.Add(code);
        }
        else
        {
            result.Add(code);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```